# How to get rid of ‘Other’ in storage

Tags: iphone, ios, storage

My iPhone does not have that much space left, so I went into storage and it seems this `Other` is taking up a lot of space and I’m wondering how I can minimise this. I know there is another question exactly like this, but from what I can tell it doesn’t seem relevant to iOS 11 (which is what I’m on).

Comment: Other is storage from apps and the operating system, including temporary files. If you have apps that store data on the phone you can delete the app and remove their data if you no longer need them. Also you can back up your device, wipe it and restore using the last backup and that will often clear some of the files in Other.

Comment: Thanks, that’s the answer I was looking for. I would accept it, except for its a comment.

Comment: I have made it an Answer, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other is storage from apps and the operating system, including temporary files. If you have apps that store data on the phone you can delete the app and remove their data if you no longer need them.

Also you can back up your device, wipe it and restore using the last backup and that will often clear some of the files in Other.

Answer (score 2):

Either offload apps, or just delete unused apps. "Other" is the internal storage from apps, so offloading apps technically removes them.

Unless you just want to free up space, then do that or delete photos. A lot of videos and pictures takes up lots of storage.

Answer (score 0):

Other is basically App Data. To free this space you can Offload an app.

**Offloading an app**

Go to Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage -> Tao on any app -> Offload app:

[image]

This frees up any storage by the app but keeps your documents and data if you re-download it.

**Storage suggestions**

If you are on a compatible iOS version when you go into iPhone Storage there should be Storage suggestions like offloading apps or uploading to iCloud:

[image]

**Uploading to iCloud**

If you have enough space in iCloud you can upload your documents and photos onto it so it doesn’t take space on your phone.

If you go to Settings -> [your name] -> iCloud you can select what to upload to iCloud. Photos takes up quite a bit of space so you can upload photos to iCloud.

Additional space can be purchased at a monthly rate.

**Exporting photos or documents to your computer**

If you have a Mac or other computer you can connect your phone and export some photos and videos that you don’t look at a lot or documents you don’t use a lot. Bare in mind though if you need them you won’t have them j less you have your computer so iCloud is better.

**Clearing up photos**

You can manually clear up your photos. There are some apps and tools for your computer that will check for duplicate photos.

[Here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/remo-duplicate-photos-remover/id1066797785?mt=8) is a duplicate checker for iOS. I haven’t tried it but it seems to have good reviews.